# Pass variables through functions in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to pass global variables through a function. For example

```
def start():
    global var

    if var == 0:
        print("Error")
    else:
        while var> -1:
            print(var)
            var = var - 1
```

Comment: What do you mean by *pass global variables through a function*?

Comment: So what's the matter with the code? It looks fine to me. You aren't really passing, so much as you are explicitly allowing global access.

Comment: So if you had a global out of a function you could access it in a function.

Comment: Malik , it comes up with the error NameError: name 'var' is not defined

Comment: Then there is no `var` in the global scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your start function explicitly allows access to a global variable named `var`. As evidenced by your error, you have no such variable defined. Please initialize the variable before the function:

```
var = 25

def start():
    global var

    # the rest of your function
    # goes here after global var
```

Comment: It says that var (in the function) is not defined?

Comment: The bottom line is you need `var` to be defined outside of the function before the function.

Comment: On the other hand you really should try to write your code without using `global`.